# change geometry feature to existing database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geo

I am using a script to import geometry features into a database. I will outlay the script below. The script works great if importing all the geo_features. However my issue is, if i want to change some of the features, then this script deletes the whole table and inputs only the changes. As the file I am importing only has the new features to be added, or the changes needed to make.

The table contains 1000's of rows. so to empty it, etc is not a option.

Can someone guide me into how i adapt this script, so that if i want to add to existing table in the DB, or change rows which are already in the table in the DB?

Script:

```
<?php   
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'sample');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
$file=file_get_contents("wf.geojson");
$contents=json_decode($file);
echo "processing...";
mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM geo_features") or die("delete error");
for($i=0;$i<count($contents->features);$i++){
    $type=$contents->features[$i]->properties->type;
    $name=$contents->features[$i]->properties->name;
    $aisle=$contents->features[$i]->properties->aisle;
    $floormap_id=$contents->features[$i]->properties->id;
    $g=$contents->features[$i]->geometry->coordinates[0];
    $gt=$g[0][0]." ".$g[0][1];
    for($j=1;$j<count($g);$j++){
        $gt.=",".$g[$j][0]." ".$g[$j][1];
    }
    $geometry="POLYGON((".$gt."))";
    $sql="insert into geo_features
                    (id,geometry,type,name,floormap_id)             
            values('$floormap_id',GeomFromText('$geometry'),
                    '$type','$name','1')";
    echo $sql;
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("error");
}
echo "success!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM geo_features")
```

You should also add a part like:

```
where id in (...list of ids...)
```

And list all ids in (...). If you run only DELETE FROM TABLE, than you delete everything. If you run DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (criteria) than you delete from table things that only satisfy specific criteria, like id values are in list.
If you cannot provide ids, than you have to come up with rules how to determine those rows.

In addition, instead of DELETE/INSERT you can use UPDATE clause.